# String.slice() data from a file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, string, fs

I have a file, for example this one, message.txt:

```
0;1;2;3;4;6;8;9
```

Then to read it, first check if it exists and then, get your data in a variable

```
const fs = require('fs')

if (fs.existsSync('message.txt')) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('message.txt', 'utf8')
    console.log(data)
} else {
    console.log("Error")
}
```

how can I do to divide the string, by ';' and take out each number by console?

Comment: can you rephrase *and take out each number by console?* the obvious thing is `data = data.split(';')`, then you have an array you can loop through, remove an item etc, then `data.join(';')` back together.

Answer (score 0):

```
const string = "0;1;2;3;4;6;8;9";
const arr = string.split(";");
```

Now, `arr` contains an array of all the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs')

if (fs.existsSync('message.txt')) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('message.txt', 'utf8')
    var arr = data.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(i, arr[i])
    }
    // console.log(data)

} else {
    console.log("Error")
}
```